# How to write a stub with RSpec for a Rails method which calls a block and doesn't return value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, block

I have a function defined like this in my controller:

```
def respond_with(action = 0, &block)
  if block_given?
    response = get_response
    block.call( MyResponse.new(response) )
  end
end
```

With that I can query the response object:

```
respond_with do |response|
  case response.status
  when 'ok'
  when 'errors'
   #etc etc...
end
```

I can just call it without the block of course if I want.

If I had a function which returned a value it would be something like

```
controller.should_receive(:respond_with).with(DO_SOMETHING).and_return(something)
```

It would be ok for

```
def respond_with(action = 0)
  ...
  response
end
```

How do I check that the block is called with a specific value in the |response| ?

Comment: Re: "I can just call it without the block of course if I want" -  What would be the purpose of calling `respond_with` without a block? Is there more to the definition?

Comment: Come to think of it, what's the purpose of providing a block to it, since their is no `yield` or invocation of the block?

Comment: When I wrote this, I tried to give it a proper name. I'd better call it perform_something_and_respond_with_if_user_provides_a_block. :)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see any role that the block plays other than as a boolean parameter to control the execution of the `if` statement.

Comment: It's not relevant to the question, but anyway :) - It's similar to Rails' respond_to do |r| where you can then query the r about it's nature and execute stuff on it - all optionally.

Comment: But `respond_to` yields to the block. That's what I'm not seeing - any `yield`. Did you just not show that aspect of the code?

Comment: Or does `get_response` do the `yield`?

Comment: Correct, should be block.call() instead of return. Was just quickly extracting the essence :) Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a "yield matcher" as described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/yield-matchers#yield-with-args-matcher

For example, you could do:

```
expect {|b| controller.respond_with(&b)}.to yield_with_args(MyResponse)
```

if you just wanted to check that the block was called exactly once with a `MyResponse` argument.

Comment: I just upvoted your question because this really is confusing! Part of this is old vs. new RSpec style, but I think fundamentally there may be no way to check both the arguments being passed into the function which accepts the block _and_ check that the function yields properly to the block. It seems like you can only do one or the other for a given execution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
.and_return(something)
```

I use:

```
.and_yield(api_response_mock)
```

That does the job. And since the block get a response object, the gem rspec-mocks comes handy here.

Comment: Yeah, this confirms that the controller receives the method call, but instead of validating that the controller yields properly, it _mocks_ the yield behavior. :-)